# Significance of loss in classification with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a three layer neural network with keras:

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
                     input_shape=input_shape, strides=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg)))

    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channels))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same",
                     input_shape=input_shape, strides=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg)))

    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channels))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same",
                     input_shape=input_shape, strides=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg)))

    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channels))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(neurons, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.50))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

My data has two classes, and I am using sparse categorical cross entropy:

```
 model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
 history = model.fit(x=X, y=y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                            shuffle=True,
                            callbacks=callbacks,
                            verbose=1)
```

My data has the following shape:

X: (232, 100, 150, 3)
y: (232,)

Where X are images and y is either 1 or 0, because of using the sparse loss function

The loss is very high for both accuracy and validation, even if the training accuracy is 1! I get values over 20 for the loss, which I understand are not reasonable.

If I set the model to try for a few epochs and output the predictions for the labels and the true values, and I get the categorical cross entropy from them, the value I get is <1, as expected, even when I make the calculation with keras' function (I change to categorical because the sparse gives an error)

```
21/21 [==============================] - 7s 313ms/step - loss: 44.1764 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 44.7084 - val_acc: 0.7857 

cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

    pred = model.predict(x=X_val, batch_size=len(X_val))
    loss = cce(true_categorical, pred)
    Categorical loss 0.6077293753623962
```

Is there a way to know exactly how this is calculated and why the high values? Batch size is 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loss printed by Keras is the **total** loss. 
Regularization **is also a loss** added to the model based on the value of the weights.

Since you have **a lot** of weights, you also have a lot of contributions to the total loss.

That is why it's big. 
If you remove the regularization, you will see the final loss equal to the categorical crossentropy loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, this seems to be what I was looking for so I will accept it. Any chances that you know where the full loss definition is, including regularization, class weights...?

Comment: Do you mean in the source code? No, it's a complicated code to go through.